# Aggregate SQL function MAX

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have 2 tables. Student and test. I would like to make a query which gets the student name (firstname and lastname) of the student which got the highest value in "test.test_results". I have tried 2 queries but both do not give me the output I want:

```
 SELECT student.studentFirstName, student.studentLastName, test.test_results,  FROM student INNER JOIN test ON student.studentID = test.studentID where MAX(test.test_results) ;
```

This Query is wrong i think and gives me an error.

```
   SELECT student.studentFirstName, student.studentLastName, test.test_results, MAX(test.test_results)  FROM student INNER JOIN test ON student.studentID = test.studentID;
```

This Query runs and gives me the student who got the highest result however it creates an extra column named "MAX(test.test_result)"

How can I make a query which gives me the name of the student who got the highest test_results from the table test.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery to find the highest test result, and then select a row from student based on that value.

```
SELECT student.studentFirstName, student.studentLastName, test.test_results FROM student INNER JOIN test ON student.studentID = test.studentID WHERE test.test_results = (SELECT MAX(test_results) FROM test)
```

Here you `SELECT MAX(test_result) FROM test` and then you select the student that is associated with that value.

Comment: That works thank you, but is it possible with one query or is there a more efficient way?